# boostrap 3 vertically centering text next to elements

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

Hey I'm using bootstrap 3 to make a webpage, and there's an issue I keep running into.  When ever I have a container, and then inside of it some text next to a button, or a text field or a drop down, the text is never as vertically big as the button, text field, etc, and so never ends up being vertically centered with the element.

I made a js fiddle example, you can see pretty quickly what I'm talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/8h3WB/1/

It seems like with bootstrap, or maybe css in general there should be a way to fix this.  Thanks in advance for any help I can get.

code in the fiddle is as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <p class="pull-left">press button</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lp pull-left">Save</button>    
    <br class="clear-fix" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col-xs-12 {
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### http://jsbin.com/eqeNisIh/1/edit

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <lable>press button</lable>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>    
</div>
</form>
```

OR

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <lable>press button</lable>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>    
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

There are a couple ways with Bootstrap 3.x and forms. If it's not a form, you'd use a tag that is inline (like a span) or you'd modify the p tag to be display:inline;

```
<div class="container">
      <span>press button</span>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>    
</div>
```

OR

```
  <div class="container">
      <p class="display-inline">press button</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.display-inline {display:inline}
```

If you want a dropdown next to text:

```
.display-inline {display:inline}
.display-inline-block {display:inline-block}
```

HTML:

```
  <p class="display-inline">Pick a something:</p> <div class="dropdown display-inline-block">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-plus dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home <small><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></small></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="color:#1111dd;"></i> Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" style="color:#0000aa;"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-inbox" style="color:#11dd11;"></i> Pages</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="color:#dd1111;"></i> Settings</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> More..</a></li>
          </ul>
  </div>
```